# "Taking the rest" in the card game Hearts

Tags: hearts

So I understand most of Hearts and love to play it on my phone. That's where I learned it. There is one thing that I don't get, though.

It seems like when a player takes the trick 3 times or so in a row he/she will "take the rest".

I was trying to shoot the moon earlier and gave away all my low number cards. After a few rounds (the queen of spades was not even played at that point) the app said that I will take the rest and the others all got 26 points because I took all the tricks.

Can anyone explain this situation? When does someone take the rest? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is the name of the app you are using? Since I don't recall having that ever happen when playing the version of Hearts that comes with Windows.

Comment: @diego It's on my android phone and is called Hearts by KARMAN Games.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature by Karman Games is called "`auto-complete`". It is also utilized in other games they make, such as Euchre.

Basically, if there is only one mathematical outcome, then there is no point in playing the rest of the hand out (or at least, that's how Karman Games sees it).

Although it doesn't (and can't) occur to the same extent, you can technically apply this feature on tabletop as well:

If you know you have the top X cards in Hearts (or Euchre), then some people will flop their entire hand down, rather than playing each card individually.

---

Note that you may not even have the top X cards in Hearts/Euchre to do this... if you do the math correctly and/or remember what cards have already been played, you can figure out the number of hands/tricks you are guaranteed to win (so long as you play them in the correct order).

If your calculation ends up being incorrect, and you flop down your hand mistakenly, it is called a "renege" and you will be penalized for it.

Comment: In real life, people mostly do this only when they have the highest trumps.  For example, in the game of Spade, if your last 3 cards are A,K,Q of spade, you can say: "the rest are mine" and reavel your hand.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spades#The_Rest_Are_Mine_(TRAM)